# XCode stops producing product (red) IOS Static Library

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries

I have a static IOS library that produces a single .a product. The solution works fine for about 15 minutes. I can make changes and when I press build I get a new product.

After a undefined quantity of time (next morning / lunch / read an email) the solution will build without error, but, the product will not be replaced with the new version. I am only making minor changes in between builds (new log statement). I have no errors or new warnings.

My current work around is to copy everything to a new location, create a new project, and copy back my old contents. I can now build a product again. WTF ?

What is the cause? How can I stop this?

**Specifics**
XCode 5.1

It is a Cocoa Touch Static Library. Its product is a .a file. The solution is dependent on another static library, Foundation, CFNetwork, Security and libicucore.dylib

Comment: Looks like a bug. Try Cleaning and Building and see if it works?

Comment: That was fast. Ok I cleaned and rebuilt. No change.

Comment: Hmm… open the product directory and watch it. Clean. See if the product disappears. Either way, build again and see if the timestamp changes.

Comment: The product does not disappear. Yeah, I am looking at the timestamp, no change. If I manually remove the product It turns red in XCode.

Comment: What kind of project is this? What is the product?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Hope you get an answer.

Comment: @ahruss New to XCode in general. It is a Cocoa Touch Static Library. Its product is a .a file. The solution is dependent on another static library, Foundation, CFNetwork, Security and libicucore.dylib